# How can I insert an id or class attribute into an option of a select statement in the form of ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, html-select

Currently, I have this select code in ZF2. Works great, have no issues, BUT! I want to put an id or class attribute into one of the options. Is that possible currently in ZF2?

```
    $this->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'number_of_rooms',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',

            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Number of Rooms',
                'options' => array(
                    array(
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => '- number of rooms -',
                        'disabled' => true,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => 'one bedrooms,
                        'label' => '1 Bedrooms',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => 'two bedrooms',
                        'label' => '2 Bedrooms',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'value' => 'three bedrooms',
                        'label' => '3 Bedrooms',
                    ),

                ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id'    => 'number_of_rooms',
            ),
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do two things. First would be to write your own SelectElement extending [`Zend\Form\Element\Select`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Form.Element.Select.html) and then you'd need to also write your own ViewHelper rendering the Select, easiest extending [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Form.View.Helper.FormSelect.html)

With the inbuilt Select the only valid options are:

```
//FormSelect.php #43-48
protected $validOptionAttributes = array(
    'disabled' => true,
    'selected' => true,
    'label'    => true,
    'value'    => true,
);
```

You can check this from the classes linked above.

Comment: This was actually the method I was trying to avoid ^_^; I was trying to see if someone already did it lol...I guess that's a no...thanks though.